# How to invoke AWS lambda Asynchronously from Kafka Trigger

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-lambda, error-handling, unhandled-exception

I am trying to explore how to handle Unhandled Exceptions(Say Lambda Timeouts) from lambda by invoking Asynchronously From an Apache Kafka Event Stream directly(**without Kafka-connect**).

When I attach a Kafka trigger to lambda, It appears to doesn't send the events to Asynchronous Destinations(OnFailure/OnSuccess to SNS/SQS/Lambda).
Since It doesn't detect these Destinations I came to the conclusion that lambda is getting invoked synchronously from Kafka Trigger unlike the S3 Event source(which works asynchronously and was able to Test it).

Here's my Idea of Handling the 2 kinds of Exceptions i.e **HandledExceptions**(Known application errors) and **UnHandledExceptions**(say Lambda Timeouts i.e Task killed after 5 seconds).

Since I have my code that works correctly for HandledExceptions which will get caught by Retry/DLQ topics. I am trying to understand how to catch these UnhandledExceptions by sending them to Another **Lambda Destinations OnFailure**.

Here's my sample Python Lambda code (Assume that Timeout is set to 5 Seconds and I'm trying to sleep for 25 seconds just to Test this flow)

```
def process_record(record):
headers = {}
key = {}
value = {}
try:
    key = json.loads(transform(record["key"]))
    value = json.loads(transform(record["value"]))
    headers = {k: "".join(map(chr, v))
               for list_item in record["headers"] for (k, v) in list_item.items()}

    time.sleep(15) # Intentional to just to check for Unhandled Exceptions such as Lambda timeout which was set to 5 seconds.

    # process it, everything is good then move on
    #blah blah blah code

    # otherwise assuming somewhere we got Known error hence throw it and send it retry and dlq.
    raise Exception("something went wrong")
except Exception as e:
    print(
        f"Event is failed with error, sending it to retry topic {str(e)}")

    dlq_sent = False
    if not headers:
        headers = {'process_count': 1, 'error_reason': str(e)}
    else:
        # Handle the next time failure by sending to either retry topic or dlq topic
        process_counter = int(headers["process_count"])+1
        headers["process_count"] = process_counter
        headers["error_reason"] = str(e)
        if(process_counter > 3):
            # send it to DLQ
            headers["process_count"] = process_counter-1
            dlq_sent = True
    # send it to retry/DLQ topic
    print(f"Modified Headers are : {headers}")
    headers = [(k, bytes(str(v), 'utf-8')) for k, v in headers.items()]
    target_topic = dlq_topic if dlq_sent else retry_topic
    producedRecord = producer.send(
        target_topic, value=value, key=str(key).encode('utf-8'), headers=headers)
    print(
        f'producer response to target topic {target_topic} is {producedRecord.get()}')


def handler(event, context):
    print('**********PROCESSING*********')
    print("Event received", event)
    x: dict = event["records"]
    for topicData in x.values():
        for record in topicData:
            process_record(record)
```

Comment: This seems like a very broad question - please try to reduce it to a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: If the lambda times out, the rest of the code shouldn't run, so there's nothing to catch. Besides that, records are immutable, and each event should be unique, so unclear how you expect headers to indicate any aggregate count unless your lambda is being triggered from the retry topic

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes this same Lambda has the triggers from actual source topic, and retry topic. Idea is that I want to try the same event 3 times(including retries) and send them to the DLQ topic if they aren't processable.
So that's not my concern actually, My problem here is if it's an Unhandled Error like Lambda Times out, then that gets retried automatically by Lambda in an infinite loop, it doesn't stop after 2 or 3 attempts. So I want to somehow handle this case as well and send it to DLQ instead of Lambda trying it infinitely

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, sorry if I overwhelmed the post with a lot of content. My problem statement is simple , I want to My Unhandled Events from the Kafka stream to be captured with the help of Lambda Destinations, which I am unable to do, It doesn't work as i expected it to work.

Comment: I think you need external storage like DynamoDB to track if your lambda is restarting from its own exceptions or not. A timeout cannot be caught within the code

Comment: @OneCricketeer, let me put this as well into the context, If I configure S3 as my Lambda Trigger and configure my lambda with similar behavior of Lambda Timeouts or uncaught key errors, I can easily get them captured, because it getting invoked asynchronously and Lambda Destination is kicking in OnFailure. But for me, the situation is to do something similar but with Kafka Trigger instead of S3 and handle this kind of uncaught scenario. I know from Lambda Code I can't do anything, it's not about the code I am looking out for, but rather a way to handle this problem.

Comment: Like I said, store a simple eventid+boolean field in DynamoDB when you get some event, and maybe a counter. Then you'll know if it's being processed again or not. This will also help reduce the number of times you need to consume from the retry topic and actually run your lambda